# 2D Array Error (Sum of element)

Tags: c++, arrays, visual-studio

I am trying to write a simple program that create 2D array and then perform a task that add up the sum of element in that 2D array. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int array [20][20];
    int i, j;
    int num_elements;
    float sum;

    for (i=0; i<num_elements; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + array[i];
    }

   return(sum);

   // output each array element's value 
   for ( i = 0; i < 20; i++ )
   {
      for ( j = 0; j < 20; j++ )
      {
         printf("a[%d][%d] = %d\n", i,j, array[i][j] );
      }
   }

   system ("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}
```

I need to create this program before I start my next question which is to modify the program so that it use functions to break it down.

I have an error that pop up which says the following:

```
error C2111: '+' : pointer addition requires integral operand
```

Also the following peice of code

```
sum = sum + array[i];
```

The problem here it says expression must have arithmetic or unscoped enum type.

Can anyone help me with this? Explaining where I'm going wrong. I have research the problem online but still can't fix it, as I try to fix it, I get more errors. 
If someone can give me an example of code, much appreciated

New Code: Works. Just need to print out the sum

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int array [3][5] = 
    {
        { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, }, // row 0
        { 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, }, // row 1
        { 11, 12, 13, 14, 15 } // row 2
    };

    int i, j=0;
    int num_elements=0;
    float sum=0;

    for (i=0; i<num_elements; i++)
    {
        sum = sum + array[i][j];
    }

    // output each array element's value 
    for ( i = 0; i < 3; i++ )
    {
      for ( j = 0; j < 5; j++ )
      {
         printf("a[%d][%d] = %d\n", i,j, array[i][j] );
      }
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You defined the array as two dimensional. However in the loop

```
for (i=0; i<num_elements; i++)
{
    sum = sum + array[i];
}
```

you use it as one dimensional. But in fact you operate with pointers to one-dimensional arrays. And compiler reports about thsi error.

Moreover neither variable num_elements nor variable sum were initialized. And nobody sees where values for the array were entered.:)

Also this return statement has no sense

```
return(sum);
```

Your plan of actions is following:

```
1. Enter values for elements of the array
2. Print out the entered array
3. Calculate the sum of all elements
4. Print out the sum.
```

Comment: The program works, I have changed the program with values in arrays. However I can't seem to print out the sum of arrays. Could you help?     The updated code is now above. I added the following line:              printf("a[%d][%d] = %d\n", sum);

Comment: I am sorry but I do not understand what can be the problem to output one value.